# SQL update datetime entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a list of dates of datetime format in two columns.

Now what I would like to do is pull each non null date from `Column1`, add one year to each value and then store it into `Column2`.

So below, after the update, `Column2` (the one with the nulls) will show:

```
2014-07-09 00:00:00.000 
2013-07-30 00:00:00.000 
2013-10-19 00:00:00.000 
2013-10-19 00:00:00.000
```

[image]

How does the syntax go? Do I need to do a select followed by an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET Column2 = DATEADD(year, 1, Column1)
WHERE Column2 IS NULL AND Column1 IS NOT NULL
```

That's gone to be ok

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Column2 = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Column1)
WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    column2 = DATEADD(year, 1, column1)
WHERE  column1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tableDates 
SET newDate = DATEADD(year, 1, oldDate) 
WHERE oldDate IS NOT NULL;
```